# Grouping string array based on object length

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
var list=['abc','ab','a','c','bc','abcdef','cdf','opq']

output:-
   var object={    
            ['a','c'],
            ['ab','bc'],
            ['abc','cdf','opq'],
            ['abdcef']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
  let list = ['abc', 'ab', 'a', 'c', 'bc', 'abcdef', 'cdf', 'opq'];
  let temp = {};
  list.map(function (item) {
       !temp.hasOwnProperty(item.length) ? temp[item.length] = [item] : temp[item.length].push(item);
  });
  let output_dict = {'output': Object.values(temp)};
  console.log(output_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is incorrect.An object cannot have data stored as shown in your required object. You can have array of arrays or object with key value pair.

In this below example array reduce method is used and inside callback the length of the the current object is checked & a key is created like `len1,len2,len3` where `1,2,3 ..` are the length of the current value. If the accumulator object contains a key by name such as `len1` or `len2` so on then push the current value to the array relevant to that key. Else create a new key by that name and add the value

```js
var list = ['abc', 'ab', 'a', 'c', 'bc', 'abcdef', 'cdf', 'opq']

let len = 'length';
let lengthObj = list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const lengthKey = `len${curr.length}`
  if (acc[lengthKey]) {
    acc[lengthKey].push(curr)
  } else {
    acc[lengthKey] = [curr];

  }

  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(lengthObj))
```